# How to customize clear behaviour of Material-UI Autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, react-redux, material-ui

I have a controlled Autocomplete component bound to a state prop from redux, that's all working. The onChange event is fired when the user clicks the "clear" icon, however the input is focused and the dropdown opens when this occurs.

How can I prevent the input focus / dropdown open only when the selected option is cleared? My preferred behaviour would be for it to return to having "null" selected and showing the label un-shrunk.

The code looks roughly like this. `value` is sourced from mapStateToProps, `onChange` comes from mapDispatchToProps.

```js
const LetterSelect: FC<Props> = ({ value, onChange }: Props) => {
    return (
        <Autocomplete
            options={["A", "B", "C", "D"]}
            value={value ?? null}
            onChange={(e,v) => onChange(v)}
            renderInput={params => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Letter" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
            )}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried event.preventDefault and event.blur ?

Comment: Have you figured out how to fix the problem?

Comment: I've posted my answer below - the default behaviour in the library was changed via a PR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't get back to this sooner: there actually wasn't a direct fix for this.

Instead, I opened an issue on the Github and it was agreed to change the default behaviour - refer to [this PR](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/18889).

Clicking the Clear icon no longer opens the Autocomplete as of v4.8.1